# How to fetch all data associated with a SharePoint web part using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api, microsoft-graph

I am wanting to fetch all of the associated data for the web parts of a SharePoint Page using the Microsoft Graph API. Is this possible through the `beta` or `v1.0` API? I can't seem to find any documented endpoint that will return what I'm looking for.

I am able to fetch a page with `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site_id}/pages/{page_id}/`. This returns something like (with some information redacted):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('{site_id}')/pages/$entity",
    "eTag": "\"{48B279E3-D519-4C35-840D-7FBE18386CFB},23\"",
    "id": "{page_id}",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-23T14:39:49Z",
    "name": "PAGE TITLE.aspx",
    "webUrl": "SitePages/PAGE TITLE.aspx",
    "title": "PAGE TITLE",
    "pageLayout": "Article",
    "createdBy": {
        "user": {
            "displayName": "User Name",
            "email": "useremail@site.com"
        }
    },
    "lastModifiedBy": {
        "user": {
            "displayName": "User Name",
            "email": "useremail@site.com"
        }
    },
    "parentReference": {
        "siteId": "{site_id}"
    },
    "contentType": {
        "id": "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C41180006521624A3273949ACA91134B5BDEB6C",
        "name": "Site Page"
    },
    "webParts": [
        {
            "type": "d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8",
            "data": {
                "id": "d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8",
                "instanceId": "19af885c-15a2-4807-b342-d89777e43082"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "rte",
            "data": {
                "innerHTML": "<p>HTML content here.</p>"
            }
        }
    ],
    "publishingState": {
        "level": "published",
        "versionId": "3.0"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the full content of `rte` elements are returned, but other elements are not. The first web part returned is an image (type `d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8`) but I can't figure out how to grab the source or other properties of the image outside of the `instanceId`.

*Is there a way I can modify my API call or use the `instanceId` to make a second API call to fetch these properties?*

Since the pages I am fetching are items in a list I am also able to fetch the page with `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items/{item_id}` which returns something like:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('{site_id}')/lists('{list_id}')/items/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "\"c06280ef-c923-4089-acde-93edfb9c8f7d,22\"",
    "createdDateTime": "2019-10-18T14:41:54Z",
    "eTag": "\"c06280ef-c923-4089-acde-93edfb9c8f7d,22\"",
    "id": "{item_id}",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-10-18T19:15:41Z",
    "webUrl": "https://mysite.com/SitePages/PAGE-TITLE.aspx",
    "createdBy": {
        "user": {
            "email": "useremail@site.com",
            "id": "{user_id}",
            "displayName": "User Name"
        }
    },
    "lastModifiedBy": {
        "user": {
            "email": "useremail@site.com",
            "id": "{user_id}",
            "displayName": "User Name"
        }
    },
    "parentReference": {
        "id": "{parent_id}",
        "siteId": "{site_id}"
    },
    "contentType": {
        "id": "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C41180006521624A3273949ACA91134B5BDEB6C",
        "name": "Site Page"
    },
    "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('{site_id}')/lists('{list_id}')/items('{item_id}')/fields/$entity",
    "fields": {
        "@odata.etag": "\"c06280ef-c923-4089-acde-93edfb9c8f7d,22\"",
        "FileLeafRef": "PAGE-TITLE.aspx",
        "Title": "PAGE TITLE",
        "Description": "Page description…",
        "LinkTitle": "PAGE TITLE",
        "Category": "Custom Field Value",
        "promoted": "2",
        "id": "{item_id}",
        "ContentType": "Site Page",
        "Created": "2019-10-18T14:41:54Z",
        "Modified": "2019-10-18T19:15:41Z",
        "_CheckinComment": "",
        "LinkFilenameNoMenu": "PAGE-TITLE.aspx",
        "LinkFilename": "PAGE-TITLE.aspx",
        "DocIcon": "aspx",
        "FileSizeDisplay": "5144",
        "ItemChildCount": "0",
        "FolderChildCount": "0",
        "_ComplianceFlags": "",
        "_ComplianceTag": "",
        "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
        "_ComplianceTagUserId": "",
        "_CommentCount": "",
        "_LikeCount": "",
        "_DisplayName": "",
        "Edit": "0",
        "_UIVersionString": "4.0",
        "ParentVersionStringLookupId": "22",
        "ParentLeafNameLookupId": "22"
    }
}
```

This endpoint gives the fields associated with the page (or list item in this case) but does not return any information on the associated web parts.

*Is it possible to modify the list item API query to get the web parts for the item and all of their properties?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph API is fairly limited when it comes to SharePoint as a resource. There is no endpoint for getting Webpart information, unfortunately. Hopefully, it will be added eventually.